# Empty space on top my GridView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, styles, android-actionbar

I have this 3 column vertically scrollable GridView with a navigation drawer for navigation but there's a big empty space between the action bar and the top row of the grid. This is the layout. I've added android:layout_alignParentTop="true" but it didn't matter. The blank space has the exact height of the action bar so maybe that means something. Tapping any of part of the blank spaces highlights it showing its borders aligning wits the column it is placed. Tapping any of the 3 spaces takes you to the full image of the first thumbnail. The rest of the grid functions normally. Also, every other section item of the menu in the nav drawer returns a fragment that renders properly annexed to the action bar - and they don't even have the android:layout_alignParentTop="true attribute - except for the main screen, which is the thumbnails gridview. The code:

activity_main:

```
    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:id="@+id/content_frame"
    android:background="#111"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/menu_drawer"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp"
    android:background="#222"/>
```

main_grid_fragment:

```
<GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/gridView"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:columnWidth="@dimen/image_thumbnail_size"
android:horizontalSpacing="@dimen/image_thumbnail_spacing"
android:numColumns="auto_fit"
android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
android:verticalSpacing="@dimen/image_thumbnail_spacing" >
```

grid_main.xml:

```
<GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/gridView"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:columnWidth="@dimen/image_thumbnail_size"
android:horizontalSpacing="@dimen/image_thumbnail_spacing"
android:numColumns="auto_fit"
android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
android:verticalSpacing="@dimen/image_thumbnail_spacing" >
```

drawer_items:

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@android:id/text1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:textSize="22sp"
android:fontFamily=""
android:gravity="center_vertical"
android:paddingLeft="22dp"
android:paddingRight="22dp"
android:textColor="#fff"
android:background="?android:attr/activatedBackgroundIndicator"
android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeightSmall"/>
```

layout_drawer:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/layout_drawer"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall"
android:gravity="center_vertical"
android:paddingLeft="16dp"
android:paddingRight="16dp"
android:textColor="#fff"
android:background="?android:attr/activatedBackgroundIndicator"
android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeightSmall"/>
```

Comment: Can you add your item layout as well?

Comment: I've added nav-drawer layouts, I'm not sure if that' what you want. The items populating the GridView are thumbnails linked to Facebook pictures

Comment: Yes, I was asking for what layout you are inflating for the GridView items.

Comment: That was there already, it was the main_grid_fragment, I don't know why I named it like this on this thread. The real name is image_grid_fragment and I'm inflating it like: onCreateView{ View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.image_grid_fragment, container, false); return v;}

Comment: Oh, got it! Just added the view I'm inflating on top of the Fragment in the answer